# How to override command executor to a new version of Git under ~/bin my own against the old /usr/bin/git

Tags: linux, git

I got a ssh account running on a shared hosting server without root permission, after I installed the latest stable Git release via git-scm.com by "make install", the new command is successful install under my home directory which is ~/bin default automatically.

However, this new version of git seems only function with specify full path, otherwise by running command "git", it will only mapping to /usr/bin/git which is old one.

So, what should I do to correct this commend mapping issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo $PATH
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

Path is where the shell goes to look for binaries. You need to make sure it looks in ~/bin before /usr/bin/git. Check with:

```
which git
```