# Use git shortcuts with a new version, overriding old

Tags: linux, git

I'm using git on a shared hosting plan which runs a Linux distribution. Because it's shared, I don't have access to `sudo`. The machine already has git version `1.7.1` installed in `/usr/bin/`, but this version is rather prehistoric at this point. I've already used `make install` to get the current version `2.14.1`, which is in `~/git-2.14.1/`. As detailed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895583/how-to-override-command-executor-to-a-new-version-of-git-under-bin-my-own-agai), I can access the correct version of git from the command line like so:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.14.1
```

which was a simple change to the `$PATH` variable, in the `~/.bash_profile`, so I can use git just fine.

I have a list of shortcuts in my `~/.gitconfig` file that make git much faster for me to use:

```
[alias]
    co = checkout
    st = status
    ci = commit
    ... etc etc etc
```

When I invoke these (e.g. `git st`), I get the results from the wrong version of git. It goes back to `1.7.1`. If I type out the full command (e.g. `git status`), it uses the correct version of git.

I also have these commands in my `~./bashrc`:

```
git () {
    case "$*" in
        st* ) shift 1; command ~/git-2.14.1/git status "$@" ;;
        * ) shift 1; command ~/git-2.14.1/git "$@" ;;
    esac
}
```

Which I have `source`-ed since writing.

I have also tried:

```
alias git="~/git-2.14.1/git"
```

To no avail.

Is there a work-around that would allow me to use these shortcuts with my preferred version of git? I am imagining a way to hide the config file from the other version by redirecting the pointer to a different location, but I have no knowledge of the existence of any such pointer.

Alternatively, is there a way to totally disable the previous version of git without `root` access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found. If I took out the alias section of the `.gitconfig`, the aforementioned shell wrapper function worked. If I removed that and restarted the ssh connection, nothing worked (as expected).

I found, with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650494/setting-up-a-custom-git-installation), that there is a magical `GIT_EXEC_PATH` variable which tells git where to find tools like `git-add`, `git-commit`, `git-status`, et. al.. Uncommenting my alias section of the `.gitconfig` file and using

```
$ export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/path/to/my/new/git's/executables/
```

made it possible to use the aliases in the `.gitconfig` file. For me the path that worked was the same folder as I installed into: `~/git-2.14.1`.You can check the current value of `GIT_EXEC_PATH` with:

```
$ git --exec-path
/path/to/my/new/git's/executables/
```

Also, `echo $GIT_EXEC_PATH` works as well. My understanding is that git uses its aliases not through the instance of git which called `git <alias>`, but rather directly through the executables in it's exec path.

Note: for me,

```
$ git --exec-path=/path/to/my...
```

did not work, but if I understand correctly, this is the equivalent command.

**TL;DR**: add the path to the new executables (`git-add`, `git-status`, etc.) in your `.bash_profile`:

```
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=/your/path/
```

Comment: Nice find with `GIT_EXEC_PAT` (that I described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43432410/6309). +1

Answer (score 1):

> When I invoke these (e.g. git st), I get the results from the wrong version of git. It goes back to 1.7.1

That is not what I see in my Ubuntu session.

I have in my .gitconfig

```
[alias]
        st = status
        br = branch
        v = !git version
```

That means I type `git v`, to check `git version` (which is the same as `git --version`).

If I change my PATH to a new compiled Git, I do see a different version.

```
vonc@VONC:~/gits$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
vonc@VONC:~/gits$ which git
/usr/bin/git
vonc@VONCAVN7:~/gits$ git v
git version 2.13.0

vonc@VONC:~/gits$ export PATH=~/gits/v2.14.0/bin:$PATH
vonc@VONC:~/gits$ git v
git version 2.14.0
```

Comment: I don't get the same results. I added `v = !git version`, and even when I do `~/git-2.14.1/git v`, I still get: `git version 1.7.1`. This even persists when I do: `export PATH=~/git-2.14.1/:$PATH` and `export PATH=~/git-2.14.1:$PATH`

Comment: @M.Davis Yes, because the ! opens a sub-shell in which your path is not the same. Are you sure you don't have an alias or a function 'git' anywhere which could have precedence?

Comment: Looks like git had its own! You pointed me in the correct direction though, thanks